# How to clean dryer ducts . Home is built on a slab

Tags: cleaning, dryer, ducts

My home sits on a slab, I can only assume that the dry duct runs from the wall and under the house ( no crawl space.). there is a large pipe that exits the house on the outside where the cap is located.. How on earth do I clean that duct out..It doesn't look like there are any curves.. but who know.. My dryer is taking much longer on high setting to dry clothes..

Comment: Can you see into the duct to see where it goes?  Maybe you can borrow an [inspection camera](http://www.harborfreight.com/digital-inspection-camera-61839.html)?

Answer (score 1):

It's very important to clean your dryer air duct at least annually.  Accumulated dust in them is a common source of house fires.  Usually they come apart in sections.  Typically what you do is remove the sections and vacuum or brush out the dust.  They also make telescoping dusters that have a round duct-sized brush on a flexible wire that you can use to push the dust through.

Answer (score 0):

[Rovac Systems](http://www.rovacsystems.com/) makes a dryer duct cleaning system. A basic kit consists of:

- a vacuum with 12 foot section of 3" ID hose (P/N [8581](http://www.rovacsystems.com/dryer_access_pgs/vac_lrg.html) or [8501](http://www.rovacsystems.com/dryer_access_pgs/vac_sm.html))
- a Wye pipe (P/N [8521](http://www.rovacsystems.com/dryer_access_pgs/y_adpt.html))
- a 25-feet "residential rod kit" (P/N [5185](http://www.rovacsystems.com/dryer_access_pgs/rod_kit.html)) which consists of:

  - a RodCaddy
  - 8 3-feet residential FlexRods
  - a starter rod w/ 4" brush
  - a drill adapter

You will also need a hand-held drill or impact gun that has a 1/4" square drive.

### Directions

Attach one end of the hose to the inlet of the vacuum, and attach the other end of the hose to the bottom of port of the Wye pipe. Attach the drill adapter to the drill chuck or the 1/4" square drive of the impact gun. Attach the starter rod (w/ attached 4" brush) to the drill adapter. Turn on vacuum. Insert the started rod into the top port of the Wye pipe. Operate the drill in forward (clockwise) direction which will spin the starter rod and attached 4" brush. Push the brush/rod progressively further into the Wye port until almost the entire rod is inside the Wye pipe. Then, maintaing the same clockwise direction of the drill, progressively remove the brush/rod from the Wye pipe. Stop the drill; completely remove the brush/rod from the Wye pipe. Attach another FlexRod to the started rod/brush. Re-insert the brush/rod into Wye pipe and repeat the process. Once complete, remove rod/brush, add another FlexRod, and repeat until you have used all FlexRods or you have encountered the end of your dryer duct system.

### Conclusion

For the residential rod kit (P/N 5185), expect to pay about $600. You will also need to buy a vacuum, which could be another $150-$300 dollars depending on the quality. You can buy the one Rovac sells, or you can buy a Ridgid vacuum (they are sold at Home Depot and various online resellers). In any case, it's not a cheap investment. However, it needs to be done, or your dryer will take an excessively long time to dry clothes. Your energy bill will increase. Finally, there is a chance that the lint in your dryer duct can catch on fire.

Here are a couple YouTube videos demonstrating the Rovac system:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsrPAz3gQpg
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQAXcPIpuiQ

You can also use the same system to clean your A/C ducts, but you would need a larger diameter brush, e.g. 14" (P/N [4714](http://www.rovacsystems.com/dryer_access_pgs/brush_assort1.html)).

Comment: By the way, Rovac does not sell directly to the public, and many of its dealers do not sell to private individuals (only to companies). However, I was able to find a great company that does sell to the public: [www.efireplacestore.com](http://www.efireplacestore.com/).