# Clean vent-less washer-dryer

Tags: cleaning, dryer, washing-machine

I have read some questions about cleaning the dryer ([1](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/33490/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-a-dryer-vent), [2](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5401/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-your-clothes-dryer-exhaust), and [3](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/91322/how-to-clean-dryer-ducts-home-is-built-on-a-slab)) but all answers deal with dryers *with a venting system*.

Mine, however, has no venting tube. Moreover, it is a washer-dryer (AEG, if the brand is needed).

Every time I use it I clean the filters, but the inside is not really accessible, nor the manual refers about cleaning it. My concern is about the grid you see on the right.

How can I properly clean it without harming it?

[image: grid]

Comment: Where does the humid dryer exhaust go? Is this electric or gas? And, what is this a picture of?

Comment: It is a heat pump condensing dryer. I think the picture is down the lint filter port. I would suggest a vacuum with a crevice attachment.

Comment: @DanielGriscom The picture is, as DanD. said, the lint filter port.

Answer (score 1):

I use an 18" piece of 3/4" rubber automotive heater hose to get to places like that. I slip or force one end of the hose into the hose to the vacuum cleaner and vacuum with the open end of the rubber hose. Be careful you do not damage some delicate heat transfer fins in your appliance.